# ReactiveUI and XAML ItemsSource updating to changes in ReactiveList

Tags: c#, xaml, reactiveui

I have an ItemsSource bound to a ReactiveList using

```
        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            d(this.OneWayBind(this.ViewModel, x => x.Pool.ToBill, x => x.ToBillListBox.ItemsSource));
        });
```

which fills a ListBox when the application starts. So far so good... but correct me if I'm wrong, I expected that a later change in the ReactiveList would propagate and update the ListBox.

The change I'm talking about comes from a nested property of the ReactiveList, so setting ChangeTrackingEnabled to true is the way to go... but still isn't propagated.

I'm also aware of the possiblity of subscribing to ItemChanged, is this the way to go to update my items source?

Comment: Do your list items also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: No, they don't. Is it a requirement?

Comment: If you want the `ReactiveList` to report a change in one of the items within the list, those items need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: OK. It does propagate if the properties notify the changes.